# How to remove nested objects from an array in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is my first web application and I need to delete a nested array item. How would you delete an object in Mongoose with this schema:

```
User: {
    event: [{_id:12345, title: "this"},{_id:12346, title:"that"}]
}
```

How can I go about deleting `id:12346` in mongoose/Mongo?

Answer (score 17):

Use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to remove items from an array of items like below :

```
db.User.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { event: { _id: 12346 } } }
)
```

> The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a
>   value or values that match a specified condition.

Empty object in the first parameter is the `query` to find the documents. The above method removes the items with `_id: 12345` in the `event` array in all the documents in the collection. 
If there are multiple items in the array that would match the condition, set `multi` option to true as shown below :

```
db.User.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { event: { _id: 12346 } } },
  { multi: true}
)
```

Comment: If I am reading this right it will search everything for `event { _id: 123456)` and remove it, correct? If needed I can just remove one instance by putting an ID in the first condition, correct?

Comment: It'll remove all the `items` with `_id:123456` from the array `event` in all the documents in the collection `User`. If you want to remove all the matching documents, you can just use `remove` method

Comment: `$pull` will delete specific value/values in an existing array and not the whole document that matches the condition. If you want to delete the whole document that matches the condition, use `db.collection.remove`

Comment: 4yrs later this is still the correct answer. Thanks @Supradeep!

Comment: @Supradeep what if i want to remove multiple nested objects by their ids??

Answer (score 2):

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: "12346" }, { $pull: { event: { _id: "12346" } } }, { new: true });
```

Comment: Why is it not a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Findone will search for id,if not found then err otherwise remove will work.

```
   User.findOne({id:12346}, function (err, User) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
        User.remove(function (err) {
            // if no error, your model is removed
        });
    });
```