# How to delete field in nested object mongoose

Tags: mongoose

Can i delete only field reservation by mongoose?. I try delete it but not work**
-

```
  "
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61a996dd0512631b54135969"),
        "tables" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "Counter 1",
                "_id" : ObjectId("61a996cf0512631b54135931"),
                "reservation" : {
                    "name" : "A",
                    "phone" : "12314564",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("61a996e00512631b5413597f")
                }
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Counter 2",
                "_id" : ObjectId("61a996cf0512631b54135932")
            }, 
    }
"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430675/how-to-remove-nested-objects-from-an-array-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Get the value you want to delete using the **find** method. Then update it and save it.

```
const tableValues = YourModel.find({'tables.name': 'Counter 1'});
if(tableValue.length == 1) {
   tableValue[0].reservations = undefined;
}
tableValues.save();
```